# Short rhyming riddle

Tags: word

We are a collective of four,
When you're outside, you'll see one of us for sure.
You will recognize us by looking at a tree.
So tell us, who are we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> The seasons

Reason:

> Changing seasons are evident outside and trees look different in each season.  Spring = growing leaves and buds.  Summer = full foliage.  Fall = changing colors.  Winter = no leaves (and snow covered where I live)

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> The four North, South, East and West
>  When you are outside you can only look into one directon
>  Some plants only grow on a specific side of a tree based on the cardinal direction

Comment: This answer would fit too. But I was looking for another word :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> leaf

We are a collective of four

> leaf is made up of four letters

When you're outside, you'll see one of us for sure

> you can find a leaf outside, depending where you live

You will recognize us by looking at a tree

> you will recognize the type of leaf by looking at the tree

So tell us, who are we?

> a leaf!

Comment: Your explanation may fit as well. But I was looking for the answer above :)